# Wrap text inside tabular environment without changing a lot of code

Tags: tables, spacing, line-breaking

I used the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}
\hline
 Pin Number & Pin Name & Analog Function\\
\hline
\hline
 1& 4xOUTZ& Yaw-rate or Z-rate output voltage 4 times amplified ($\pm$ 100 °/sec) \\
\hline
 2& OUTZ& Yaw-rate or Z-rate output voltage ($\pm$ 400 °/sec) \\
\hline
 3& ST& Self-test (logic 0: normal mode; logic 1: self-test) for Yaw Gyroscope \\
\hline
 4& PD& Power-down(logic 0: normal mode; logic 1: Power-down mode) for Yaw Gyroscope \\ 
\hline
 5& HP& High pass filter reset(logic 0: normal mode; logic 1: external high pass filter is 
reset) for Yaw Gyroscope \\
\hline
 6& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
 7& GND& Supply Ground \\
\hline
 8& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
 9& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
 10& Vref& Vref output from the Yaw Gyroscope IC. (Leave unconnected) \\
\hline
 11& OUTY& Roll-Rate or Y-rate output voltage ($\pm$ 400 °/sec) \\
\hline
 12& 4xOUTY& Roll-rate or Y-rate output voltage 4 times amplified ($\pm$ 100 °/sec)\\
\hline
 13& 4xOUTX& Pitch-rate or X-rate output voltage 4 times amplified ($\pm$ 100 °/sec) \\
\hline
 14& OUTX& Pitch-rate or X-rate output voltage ($\pm$ 400 °/sec) \\
\hline
 15& ST& Self-test (logic 0: normal mode; logic 1: self-test) for Pitch and Roll Gyroscope \\
\hline
 16& PD& Power-down(logic 0: normal mode; logic 1: Power-down mode) Pitch and Roll Gyroscope \\
\hline
 17& HP& High pass filter reset(logic 0: normal mode; logic 1: external high pass filter is reset) Pitch and Roll Gyroscope \\
\hline
 18& Vdd& 3.3V supply voltage \\
\hline
 19& Vref& Vref output from the Pitch and Roll Gyroscope IC. (Leave unconnected) \\
\hline
 20& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
 21& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
 22& Vref& Vref output from the IC. (Leave unconnected) \\
\hline
 23& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
 24& NC& Not connected \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

to prepare a table like this:

[image]

However you can see what my problem is. Is there a way to wrap the text in the table without changing a lot of the code I have already written?

Answer (score 3):

Try with the `tabularx` package. The relevant section of the example again:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|}
```

Of course, you can also use a different width for your table than `\linewidth`.